# Code with classes and iteration doesn't work using lists

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I need a little help with my homework:

I have a class course with the course name and grade and class with student name, age, and also in student class should be a list of all courses and their grades.

I want to use only lists. I could to it with dict but is it possible to do it with lists? each course contains name of the course and grade

The code I tried that don't do anything:

```
class Course:
    def __init__(self,coursename,grade):
      self.coursename=coursename
      self.grade=int(grade)
      self.newList=[]

    def __str__(self):
    return self.coursename+":"+ str(self.grade)

class Student:
    def __init__(self,name,age):
      self.name=name
      self.age=int(age)
      self.listCoursenamesAndGrades=[]
      #super().__init__(self,coursename,grade)


    def addCourse(self,c):
        self.listCoursenamesAndGrades.append(c)


    def __iter__(self):
     self._current = 0
     return self


     def __next__(self):
        try:
          while True:
            c=self.listCoursenamesAndGrades[self.current]
            if (self.current <len(self.listCoursenamesAndGrades)):
               self.current+=1
            if c.grade > 59:
                return c
        except IndexError:
            raise StopIteration
```

output:

```
   s1=Student("Sam",24)
   C1=Course("js",80)
   s1.addCourse(Course("Math",85))
   s1.addCourse(Course("Math",70))
   for c in s1:
     print(c)
```

and the output will be:

```
Js:80
Math:85
Math:70
```

thank you for the help!!

Comment: Does it do nothing or spit some error logs?

Comment: @HotteShen currantly after the fix I get: __str__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'c'

Comment: @bruno I deleted the student(course). I also think it's not inheritance here

Comment: Please fix your indentation!

Comment: What is your question? What specific problem do you need help with? You already are using a list.

Comment: Please share the entire error message in the question body itself. Also, variable and function names should follow the `lower_case_with_underscores` style.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `__next__` should return a *single* item; it should not be iterating over a list. For what you want, it would be simpler to put the iteration logic in `__iter__` to start:

```
def __iter__(self):
    for c in self.listCoursenamesAndGrades:
        if c.grade > 59:
            yield c
```

Since `__iter__` doesn't return `self` itself, you can have multiple independent iterators (just don't be modifying the course list in the mean time).

As an example of making `Student` an iterator with its own separate `__next__` method, you need to store the current state of iteration on the `Student` itself. For example:

```
# Since _current is an attribute of the Student instance itself,
# you can't have multiple independent iterators. Something like
#
#  i1 = iter(Student)
#  print(next(i1))
#  i2 = iter(Student)
#  print(next(i1)
#
# will print the same course twice; calling `iter(Student)` resets
# the object's iteration state.
def __iter__(self):
    self._current = 0
    return self

def __next__(self):
    try:
        while True:
            c = self.listCoursenamesAndGrades[self._current]
            self._current += 1
            if c.grade > 59:
                return c
    except IndexError:
        raise StopIteration
```

Comment: thank you! I get an error __str__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'c'. do you why?

Comment: At least in your question, the `__str__` method isn't indented properly, so you  never defined `Course.__str__`.

Comment: in visual everything ok with the indentation but maybe I send (self,c) and it wants 2 arguments in print(c)?

Comment: `__str__` shouldn't take an additional argument (you don't use `c` anyway; `self` *is* the instance of `Course` that you want to produce a `str` value from.

Comment: I fixed the c and it working! thank you! though I don't know why it only prints Math:85 and not the 2 others

Comment: Well, `C1` was never added to the student.

Comment: C should be add to the list each time self.listCoursenamesAndGrades=[]. how should I add it ? also I need to check length but I don't get anything:               def __next__(self):
              try:
                while True:
                  if(self.current<=len(self.listCoursenamesAndGrades)):
                     self.current+= 1
                  if (self.listCoursenamesAndGrades[self.current] > 59):
                    return listCoursenamesAndGrades[self.current-1]
              except IndexError:
                    raise StopIteration

Comment: Why? You never passed it as an argument to `s1.addCourse`.

Comment: it works but do you know what is wrong with the next I try to do now? ( in the code)

Comment: Two things: you are using `<=` instead of `<`, *and* you are increment `self.current` *after* you have check if it is safe to use, but before you actually use it.

Comment: I fixed it just added to your code this option. thank you a lot!